# Route doesn't populate data when page is refreshed

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, vue-router

I have a very basic site using Vue.JS, VueX, and Vue-Router.

I have two routes defined: '#/' and '#/account/'
These routes are populated with two components in .vue files, loaded dynamically at page load via [http-vue-loader](https://github.com/FranckFreiburger/http-vue-loader) (to avoid dealing with webpack/etc since the project is so small).

The '#/' view is a static component.

The '#/account' view displays the user's first and last name in `<input type="text">` boxes.

If I navigate to the '#/account' page from the '#/', the first/last name are populated properly.  But if I then refresh the browser, the textboxes become empty and don't re-populate until after I navigate to another route and back again.

The data in this component are being loaded from the global VueX store, which is being `commit()`ted on page load as the result of an AJAX call.

Why won't these fields populate upon a page refresh?

Pertinent code:

main.js: (loaded as `<script type="module">` from main html file)

```
const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        user: {firstname: '', lastname: ''}
    },
    mutations: {
        updateUser(state, user){

            state.user = { ...user }
        }
    }
})


$(document).ready(function() {
let templates = {}
templates.home = httpVueLoader('./templates/home.vue')
templates.account = httpVueLoader('./templates/account.vue')
templates.not_found = httpVueLoader('./templates/404.vue')

// Set up routes:
const routes = [
    { path: '/', component: templates.home },
    { path: '/account', component: templates.account },

    // Not found: (place this route last)
    { path: '*', component: templates.not_found }
]

const router = new VueRouter({ routes })

// Start Vue app:
const app = new Vue({
    router,
    store,
    components: {

    }
}).$mount('#vueApp')

checkLogin()    // Check if user is logged in - if so, populate VueX store with user info.

function checkLogin() {
    // Check if user is already logged on.
    console.log("Checking for login...")
    Get({
        url: 'https://[api-url]/v1/auth'
    })
    .then((result) => {
        console.log("Result: ", result)
        if (result.data.logged_in) {
            loadUI()
            store.commit('updateUser', result.data.user)
        }
        else
        {
            logout()
        }
    })
}
```

account.vue:

```
<template>
    ...

                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtFirstname" aria-describedby="txtFirstnameHelp" v-model="firstname">
                    ...
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtLastname" aria-describedby="txtLastnameHelp" v-model="lastname">
                    ...

</template>

<script>
module.exports = {
    data: function() {
        return {

            firstname: this.$store.state.user.firstname,
            lastname: this.$store.state.user.lastname
        }
    },
    ...
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

The fix is that these properties should be declared as computed properties, instead of returning them in the `data` object:

in Account.vue:

module.exports = {
    data: function() {
        return {

```
    }
},
computed: {
    firstname: function() { return this.$store.state.user.firstname },
    lastname: function() { return this.$store.state.user.lastname }
},
```

...

Comment: Correct! I suggest explaining _why_ in your answer though

Comment: I don't think this works on Vue3.   I get   error  Parsing error: In strict mode code, functions can only be declared at top level or inside a block. (6:19) I am able to access my data in the template using myStore.rates but if I refresh the page it's all gone, because when the page loads the data is not loaded yet.